# All truffle commands left segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: truffle

This is the output of `truffle compile`:

```
> Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling ./contracts/Lent.sol
> Artifacts written to /home/supernozer/MyERC20/build/contracts
> Compiled successfully using:
   - solc: 0.6.7+commit.b8d736ae.Emscripten.clang

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

As well as `truffle migrate --network ropsten --reset`:

```
...
Summary
=======
> Total deployments:   2
> Final cost:          0.0753067 ETH



Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Any solution to fix this? Or just simply ignore since it doesn't interrupt anything?

Comment: Looks like a bug in solc. You can report it on their github.

Comment: I don't think so. I was using the same version on Ubuntu 19. After I formatted everything and upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04 then this issue coming up. The same thing happened for solcjs v0.6.8 as well.

even `truffle compile --list` shows the same:

```supernozer@root:~/MyERC20$ truffle compile --list
⠼ Fetching solc version list from solc-bin. Attempt #1[
 "0.6.8",
 "0.6.7",
 "0.6.6",
 "0.6.5",
 "0.6.4",
 "0.6.3",
 "0.6.2",
 "0.6.1",
 "0.6.0",
 "0.5.17",
 ".. and 61 more. Use `--all` to see full list."
]
Segmentation fault (core dumped)```

Comment: @NOZR What node version are you using? What truffle version are you using? Can you try a different node/truffle version? Does it happen with other projects/contracts?

Comment: @Ismael I'm using Truffle v5.1.26 (core: 5.1.26) and Node v10.16.0. I'm about to install Node latest version but it doesn't let me to install HDwallet provider that's why.

Comment: @NOZR I'd suggest to try reinstall truffle and/or node, perhaps a dependency update has break something.

Comment: @Ismael i've tried to reinstall Truffle but nothing changed. About node, is that newer version of Node doesn't support Truffle HDwallet provider? Or just me? Maybe i'll update my Node to the latest version instead.

Comment: @NOZR I tried the same versions of truffle/node with truffle's metacoin sample project and it compiled without any issue in ubuntu 18.04 and windows 10. It doesn't seem an issue with truffle/node, I'd suggest to try in a VM or another computer.

Comment: You're correct! Segmentation fault message has gone. I found so many nodejs versions installed under .NVM folder. So, i completely removed all NVM, NPM, and Node. Then reinstall, it works perfectly. Would you like to add that so i can mark it as an answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what case this issue but simply re-installing / updating **Truffle** fixed the issue for me.

```
npm install -g truffle
```